# How to apply TFIDF on nltk POS Data .....?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, data-science, tfidfvectorizer

I applied nltk POS featurization to my reviews column in my panda's DataFrame.
I got the new feature, but when I'm trying to apply TFIDF vectorization on that feature it shows error like

**Error: While applying TFIDF Vectorizer** 
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute lower**

I used below code for nltk POS

```
pure_df['pre_pro_plot_synopsis_POS'] = pos_tag_sents(pure_df['pre_pro_plot_synopsis'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist())
```

Can anyone help me to pass POS data to tfidf vectorizer?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here it seems `pos_tag_sents` method created by you expects a string as paramenter, but here you are passing list as a parameter to it. So instead of this line: 
`pos_tag_sents(pure_df['pre_pro_plot_synopsis'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist())`

Try using apply method again and pass `pos_tag_sents` to it, like this:

`pure_df['pre_pro_plot_synopsis_POS'] = pure_df['pre_pro_plot_synopsis'].apply(word_tokenize).apply(pos_tag_sents).tolist()`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I'll try and get back to you :)